# Extract a value from a HTML response with Cheerio using Postman

Tags: html, postman, cheerio

I'm trying to get a value from request, that returns a HTML response, using Postman. I'm using Cheerio inside the script section.

The response looks like this:

```html
    <table class="etlsessions-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="someclass1">
                    <div>
                        <span>info1</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="someclass2">
                    <div>
                        <span>info2</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="someclass3">
                    <div>
                        <span>info3</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
                <th class="someclass2">
                    <div>
                        <span>info4</span>
                    </div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="someclass5">
                <td class="someclass">
                    <nobr>info5</nobr>
                </td>
                <td class="someclass6">
                    <nobr>info6</nobr>
                </td>
                <td class="someclass3">info7</td>
                <td class="someclass7">
                    <a href="http://www.google.com">someurl1</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

How I can get the `info6` value from the `someclass6` class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Cheerio is built-in to the Postman sandbox environment, you can use it to get the value of the element.

I'm not sure of your complete use-case but you could add something basic like this to the `Tests` script and print the value to the console:

```js
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text()),
    elementValue = $('.someclass6 nobr').text();

console.log(elementValue)
```

Answer (score 0):

To emphasis Danny was saying

Use the jQuery selector API to get different elements on the page reading dom

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
console.log $('.someclass6 nobr').text(); //derive any element from class 
  which has value someclass6
```

Or you can write it like this

```
console.log($("td[class$='someclass6'] nobr").text()); //derive any text value within the td tag from the class  which has the value someclass6 
console.log($("td").attr('class')) //to fetch values from the attribute(s) of tag td
```

To store it as a collection variable in postman for useage in other api calls

```
const $ = cheerio.load(pm.response.text());
var storesomeclass6 =  $('.someclass6 nobr').text();
pm.collectionVariables.set("someclass6", storesomeclass6 );
```

Answer (score -1):

Postman is a software that will allow you to make calls to API endpoints, so basically your program will be written in node.js and you will call the endpoint with postman.

In this case and using cheerio, the code will look like something like this :

```
function getResponse() {

return fetch(`${YOUR API END POINT URL}`)
.then(response => response.text())
.then(body => {
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const $info6= $('.someclass6 td );

  const info6= $info6.first().contents().filter(function() {
    return this.type === 'text';
  }).text().trim();
  const response= {
    info6,
  };

  return response;
});
}
```

Best of luck !